# Exiting from button action because of if condition

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

my application have a button that does certain things, and one of these need an NSString as argument.
This NSString is globally defined and initialized as empty:

```
NSString *myString = @"";
```

With an if basically I'm making sure that this string is never empty, otherwise the application must show an error popup.
This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    if ([myString isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSRunAlertPanel(@"Error",@"Your string is empty!", @"OK", nil, nil);

    }
    // other things
}
```

The part that I miss is: how can I block the execution of the "other things" if this condition is real?
I need something like the C `break` used into a `while`.
Thanks a lot for your replies

Comment: ummm... `else` perhaps? I've never written a line of obj-c in my life but it seems pretty obvious... I would say `return` but I'm not sure that exists in a button action.

Comment: As Doorknob of Snow said, use 'else' clause

Comment: Please find a nice tutorial on Objective-C that also covers the basics of C (Objective-C is a superset of C). If you don't know about `else` or `return` you are going to have a tough time writing your program.

Comment: actually I have C basics, and because of this I tried the ¡ `return` statement to force the program to jump that part of code but I used the return value too, so I thought that ObjC had some sort of other method to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `return;` will do the job

Comment: I tried `return 0;` but didn't worked because the function doesn't have any return value... This worked anyway, thanks!

Comment: @PeppeLaKappa: `IBAction` is a typedef for `void`, if you weren't aware.

Answer (score 0):

Write an else statement wherein you add the rest of the code which you wanna execute otherwise.Cheers